# Google Docs: Can I "include" other docs dynamically?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have a document broken up into sections for easy editing.  Is there a way to have a "master" document that includes these sections automatically?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1499/354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Documents doesn't have a way to include other documents dynamically.

One alternative is to add the content of them each time you need to print them or export to another file format like PDF.

It's worth to say that there is an add-on that could help to append several docs. It's [docAppender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docappender/lijjbnggcpkhpkabahnebgdbnepdjhff?utm_source=permalink).