# Write cell value based on the URL of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

Is there any way populate a cell in a Google sheet based on the value in the URL?

For example: If the hyperlink below was on sheetA and the link was clicked. Is there any way to get `?cell=english` into a cell in sheetB?

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=2018939279?cell=english","English")
```

Answer (score 2):

The event of someone clicking a hyperlink embedded in a spreadsheet is not visible to the spreadsheet itself. It cannot trigger any changes. (Unless the link is to some web application which is programmed to modify the spreadsheet).

As for extracting the URL from a cell with `=hyperlink` formula -  this can't be done with built-in Sheets functions, but there is a custom function (implemented in Google Apps Script) which does that: see  [Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89557).

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to do so on click-event, but it can be faked to some degree:

- **cell SheetA!A1:** insert custom checkbox via data validation
- **cell SheetA!B1: `=IF(A1=1, HYPERLINK("https://www.themoviedb.org/", "English"), )`**
- **cell SheetA!C1: `=IF(B1<>"", HYPERLINK("https://www.themoviedb.org/"), )`**
- **cell SheetB!A1: `=INDIRECT("SheetA!C1")`**

> [image: 1]
>
> [image: 2]
>
> [image: 3]
>
> [image: 4]

the other approach would be to mask that link via URL shortener like **https://bitly.com/** and scrape click-count via **`IMPORTXML()`** and then use simple **`IF()`** statement in a way:
 **`IF(IMPORTXML(imported click-count)>2(click-counts), INDIRECT("SheetA!C1"), )`** 
to detect ocured click and fill cell **SheetB!A1** - the only downside is that it's just one time trigger detector.