# How to change Google Sheets hyperlinks into HTML "a href" links?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to change the multiple links in a  Google Sheets from normal sheet hyperlinks such as:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://traveltractions.com","Travel Tractions")
```

into:

```
<a href="https://traveltractions.com">Travel Tractions</a>
```

How can I do this in bulk?

Comment: Thanks, I've played with this a little but admittedly I'm not very good at it. Do you know a script I could try or point me to a place where there are already made scripts for this? Surely it's a common problem, I looked for extensions and add-ons but nothing was definitive.

Comment: Can you give an idea of how they're laid out? Are you wanting to bulk change a list of just links, or are they scattered about in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Maybe an easier solution is to use Find/Replace. Just be sure to check the search inside formulas checkbox

Comment: @pnuts suggested I change "Also search within formulae:. His formula didn't work but now at least I can do a search and replace. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be impractical if your links are scattered throughout a sheet, but should be viable if say all in a column (assumed `A`):

- Replace all `=` in ColumnA with say `#` with `Also search within formulae`
- Enter, say in B1, and copy down to suit:

  ```
  =substitute(trim("<a href="&mid(A1,12,find(",",A1,12)-12)&">"&mid(A1,find(",",A1)+2,len(A1))),char(34)&")","</>")
  ```
- Copy ColumnB, Paste special, Paste values only over the top
- Replace all `#` in ColumnA with `=` (or delete ColumnA?)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Next, two of them:

1. Using built-in FIND/REPLACE with the find insi

   1. Replace `=HYPERLINK(` by `<a href="`.
   2. Replace `,"` by `>`.
   3. Replace `")` by `</>`
2. Using Google Apps Script

   1. Use the getFormula(range) or getFormulas(range) Google Apps Script's methods to get the formula(s),
   2. Use replace(string) JavaScript method

For examples, checkout [Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89557/88163)

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly rudimentary, but a Google Apps Script solution could be as follows:

```
function createHref(url, title){
  /* Create the URL and return it. */
 return '<a href=' + url + '>' + title + '</a>';
}

function flatten(arr) {
  /* Flatten n-dimensional array. */
  return arr.reduce(function(flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(
      Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten
    );
  }, []);
}

function setCellVal(row, col, val) {
  /* Function to make setValue() less annoying. */ 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(row, col)
    .setValue(val);
}

function createLinks() {
  /* Main function */
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(); // Active spreadsheet object.
  const linkCol = 1; // Column for links.
  const outputCol = 2; // Column for formatted link output.
  const numRows = sh.getLastRow();
  const myRegexp = /\("(.*?)".*?\"(.*?)"/g; 

  var linkList = sh.getRange("A2:A").getFormulas();
  linkList = flatten(linkList.filter(String));  
  var match = myRegexp.exec(linkList);

  var count = 2;
    while (count < numRows + 1) {
      setCellVal(count, outputCol, createHref(match[1], match[2]));
      match = myRegexp.exec(linkList);
      count++;
    }
}
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18APMBNFkaosgt4luuP56EdiJYHANMrHUgUu1I2wLPXM/edit?usp=sharing) to a working example that you can copy and try for yourself.