# Google Sheets - Extract URL From a Cell Containing a Hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets

I am using an **IFTTT** recipe which populates **Google Sheets** cells with a hyperlink formula like this one:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://twitter.com/guardian/status/941765632642691073", "link")
```

The result in the Google Sheet are cells with the hyperlink, pointing to tweet URLs, like the one below:

| **[link](http://twitter.com/guardian/status/941765632642691073)** |

Is there a way to extract ONLY the URL from the hyperlink into another cell using a formula or a combination of formulas without the use of macro code?
The desired result is the following:

| **[link](http://twitter.com/guardian/status/941765632642691073)** | http://twitter.com/guardian/status/941765632642691073 |

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell)

Comment: The problem is that the IFTTT recipe delivers a hyperlink. I have hundreds of hyperlinks that i need to extract the URL and using macros seem to burden the server so much that it is not viable. The best would be to find a way to extract the URL using sheet formula only

Comment: There is no built-in function that does that. Have you considered to use another IFTT recipe?

Comment: I ended up reconstructing the URL using the REGEXMATCH inside a copy recipe I made in IFTTT. I guess the main obstacle is the limited API handlers offered by IFTTT to begin with. Zapier offers greater API access but it costs.

Comment: post that as answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution... I ended up reconstructing the URL using the REGEXMATCH formula inside a copy recipe I made in [**IFTTT**](https://ifttt.com). That throws the formula with the raw data directly into the **Google Sheet** cell and the process to extract the URL is happening on the fly. The main obstacle is the limited API handlers offered by **IFTTT** to begin with. I found that [**zapier**](https://zapier.com) offers greater API access, especially when comes to **Twitter**, but it costs.