# How to extract link URL from a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a cell with `=hyperlink("http://www.example.com", "Example.com")` in it. What formula can I use to extract just the link out of that cell?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522305/google-sheets-how-do-you-get-the-formula-from-a-cell-instead-of-the-value

Comment: The duplicate linked to answers my question here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell