# Check for regexmatch in multiple ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

[image: All Publications][image]
I have a sheet that auto-populates with a sub-set of articles (each a row with a column representing various information such as title, year of publication, author name, etc...) on the basis of a set of tags (that have their own column in D2:D). There is a master "All Publications" tab and using the filter function I check each cell in the 'Primary Category' column ('All Publications'!B5:B) and if it matches one of the cells in the 'Tags for Tab' column that article is included. Example: I might want all articles with a primary category of "Rot" to be included under a new sheet called 'Rot Articles'. I have this functionality in place already with the following filter:

```
=FILTER('All Publications'!A5:A, 
 REGEXMATCH(LOWER('All Publications'!B5:B), LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE,D3:D))))
```

D3:D is the column where the tags for the given sheet are kept. I now have two additional columns called 'Secondary Category' ('All Publications'!C5:C) and 'Tertiary Category' ('All Publications'!D5:D) respectively.

I want to be able to include any article that has the keyword 'Rot' *in any of the three categories (primary, secondary, tertiary)*. The query above only checks the primary category. In other words: I want an article to populate my sheet if a match for any of the tags in 'Rot Articles'!D3:D is found in the ranges `'All Publications'!B5:B OR 'All Publications'!C5:C OR 'All Publications'!D5:D`. How do I do this? Its important to know that these articles contain hyperlinks and so *using the QUERY function is not an option*.

Anyone that wants to play with this toy example is free to access the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOxisNd_Nw-_YKHJHCbi1qWvoVh3K8Tu9xxAxee3520/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can still try a query, you just need to extract the url then reassemble the hyperlink.

[Here's a stackexchange answer to extract the url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89588/222777)

Add this in the script editor

```
/** 
 * Returns the URL of a hyperlinked cell, if it's entered with hyperlink command. 
 * Supports ranges
 * @param {A1}  reference Cell reference
 * @customfunction
 */
function linkURL(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      var url = formulas[i][j].match(/=hyperlink\("([^"]+)"/i);
      row.push(url ? url[1] : '');
    }
    output.push(row);
  }
  return output
}
```

Now you just have to add a column with something like `=linkURL(range)`

In a second time you just have to reconstruct the hyperlink

```
=HYPERLINK(range,description)
```