# Custom function on Google Sheets that can extract hyperlinks from formulated cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I recently found this post, which is so close to my solution, but not quite there!

[Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell/89588#89588?newreg=21491f5cb57d4ef0965035647aabd70a)

The issue with this custom formula (`=LinkURL()`) is that it can only accept a cell reference e.g. `=LinkURL(A1)`. I want to be able to use a vlookup formula within this function like this:

In column G, I'm using the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G:G)=1, "Retail price", IF(ISBLANK(B:B), "",vlookup(B:B,{'NEW - Product Analysis'!B:B,'NEW - Product Analysis'!E:E},2,false))))`

Which correctly pulls specific column data from another sheet which is my main tab with the data. The data this pulls over is a hyperlinked cell, with a financial value as the string. I want to separate these in the destination sheet i.e. I want to pull the hyperlink into one column, and the value in a separate column. The only way I could think to do this is by using the `=LinkURL(G2)`, but this does not work. I therefore tried to use vlookup to pull the data directly into the `=LinkURL` function but it would not accept a formula, only a cell reference.

On another note, I was also unable to get the `=LinkURL` function to accept the string from another cell to be used as the cell reference. Is this possible?

Apologies in advance if I have not clearly articulated what I want. Let me know and I will attempt to explain more clearly.

Comment: Have you tried the custom function in [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89564/88163) to the referred question?

Comment: Well I did, @Rubén, and when the target is the value of a vlookup, the function returns "undefined".

Comment: I have a feeling that these fields are going to be fashioned piecemeal. FWIW#1, if you apply `.toString()` to the hyperlinked value of vlookup, then you get the "label" section of the hyperlink.

Comment: @Rubén FWIW#2, if we assume that the VLOOKUP search key is in cell E1, the VLOOKUP range is A1:B1 (label in cell A1 and the hyperlink formula is in cell B1), and this formula is in Cell E3 `=ADDRESS(MATCH(E1,A1,0),2, 1)`. This will return $B$1. If you then run linkURL (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89588/196152), then the formula will return the url.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz. As you already mentioned the custom function in answer requires an address instead of a reference (`"A1"` insetad of of `A1`)  :)

Comment: By the way it's not possible to use my custom function or `LinkURL`to get the URLs from the results of a built-in function  like `VLOOKUP` because they return values not references. IMHO the best approach is first get the URLs then do the `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: @Rubén I have used your custom function, which I tried to explain in my question (perhaps this wasn't clear enough - apologies). The function works great if it is directly referencing a cell with the =hyperlink function. However, I am trying to extract the formula from a cell when it meets certain conditions via the vlookup function. I will use your later suggestion instead, and in the source sheet extract the hyperlink and in the destination sheet pull the already extracted value.

Comment: @Rubén is it possible to rewrite the code for =linkurl at all to accept a reference as string via =indirect e.g. in cell A2 the contents are B1:B9 and I want to do =linkurl(indirect(A2)) in order to use the range B1:B9. Is this possible?