# Extracting Website Title from Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I extract the website title name only from one cell and auto paste it in another cell in Google Sheets?

I have a spreadsheet where we are constantly adding URLs from multiple different websites & we need to then manually input what website its for.

For example:

google.com/jhsdgfjkhsgd in A1, I need to manually input Google in B1
wikipedia.com/therock in A2, I need to manually input Wikipedia in A2

Is there a formula I can paste into the entire A column or script I can use to do this automatically?

I saw a previous post on here ([Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell)) but those options did not work for me.

Comment: *"That works beautifully! Thank you!"* Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this formula, placed in `B2`:

```
=index(regexreplace(A1:A,"\..+",""))
```

1. the regular_expression `\..+` selects all text from dot to end
2. the `regexreplace()` function replaces that selection with empty
3. the `index()` function applies that formula to all the links of column A

if all your urls have www. in front, use this formula instead:

```
=index(if(A1:A<>"",regexextract(A1:A,"\.(.+)\."),))
```

this always extracts the text contained between two points

Comment: That works beautifully! Thank you!

Although many times (actually every time) our URLS will have the whole (https - it won't let me display the https in the whole link) https://www. in front of it. 

Is there a way to adjust the formula to account for that?

Comment: I just found this:

=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"https://www.","")

Which can remove the unwanted text in front but I cannot figure out a way to combine the two forumlas without having to use multiple cells

Comment: if all your urls have www. in front, use this formula: `=index(if(A1:A<>"",regexextract(A1:A,"\.(.+)\."),))`  this always extracts the text contained between two points

Comment: Great. Remember though, you can also edit your answer to include your alternatives. Not all people make it down to comments.

Comment: @marikamitsos done :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=proper(replace(regexreplace(regexreplace(INDEX(F:F,ROW()),"https://",""),"www.",""),find(".",regexreplace(regexreplace(INDEX(F:F,ROW()),"https://",""),"www.","")),100,""))
```

This is what I ended up using as the URLs we use are from all different sites & some include the https with no www and some include both.

Answer (score -1):

I got a pretty indirect method to extract all url. Export the column of embedded url titles in html file. Then online URL extractor would do the job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).