# Embed Google Doc within a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to have a big spreadsheet with many sheets and have one sheet that has an embedded Google Doc?

This would allow me to use the Google Spreadsheet as a dashboard and individually contribute to the Docs composing it.

Comment: Related: [Embed Google Spreadsheet in Google Document](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1499/354)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A sheet of a Google Spreadsheet contains either a grid with data and formulas, or a chart that was placed on its own sheet. It cannot contain a document.