# Embed Google Spreadsheet table Withing Google Document when data contains dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, embed

I found a [great script here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/embed-google-spreadsheet-in-google-document) that will add a Google Sheet table to my Google Doc.

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
             .createMenu('Custom')
             .addItem('Update Data', 'updateData')
             .addToUi();
}

function updateData() {
  var ssUrl = ' spreadsheet url here ';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet2';   // name of sheet to use
  var rangeName = 'A1:C3';    // range of values to include 

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl)
                             .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                             .getRange(rangeName)
                             .getValues();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var ranges = doc.getNamedRanges('embeddedSheet-range');
  if (ranges.length == 0) {
    var table = body.appendTable(values);
  }
  else {
    tableRange = ranges[0];
    table = tableRange.getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getElement();
    var ind = body.getChildIndex(table);
    tableRange.remove();
    body.removeChild(table);
    table = body.insertTable(ind, values);
  }
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
  rangeBuilder.addElement(table);
  doc.addNamedRange('embeddedSheet-range', rangeBuilder.build());
}
```

This works fine with regular numbers and text, but if a cell in Google sheet is formatted as a date, for example with the value "**30/01/2020 10:58:41**"  it prevents the script form working and I get the message:

> The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for
>   DocumentApp.Body.appendTable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl)
                             .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                             .getRange(rangeName)
                             .getValues();
```

by

```
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl)
                             .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                             .getRange(rangeName)
                             .getDisplayValues();
```

The above *should* work because `getDisplayValues()` returns a 2D array having the text representation of the cell values while `getValues()` returns strings, numbers and Date objects.

Comment: Thanks Ruben  <br/>
You solution worked as charm :(  

2 more questions   

1- Is there a way to to format to the table data that I'm Adding? Specifically , **Bold the text in the header row**, **change font size of rows under the header row**, *generate the table in RTL direction**  
2- Is there a way to add the table in a specific page of the Google doc ? For example page 3?

Comment: @AzrielLider The short answer for both question is yes, there is a way. Please bear in mind that follow-up questions should be posted as new questions, but before doing that, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs