# Automatically update inserted sheets cells in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc which has linked cells to Google Sheets. I want to type a Script that automatically updates the document whenever the cells in Google Sheets are changed (it receives answers from a Google Form).
I'm New to scripts.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the work of `user79865`.

You have a Google Form which exports results to a Google Sheet; you have embeded the sheet in a Google Doc and you are looking for a way to update the Google Doc automatically whenever there is a new form response.

Your question is substantially answered in webapps question: [Embed Google Spreadsheet table Withing Google Document when data contains dates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138858/196152) which in turn was based on this webapps question [Embed Google Spreadsheet in Google Document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82225/196152).

Your scenario differs in two ways:

1 - you want to update the Google document for every new form response, and
2 - you want the update to be automatic.

---

**Installation**

You have a Google Form, Google Spreadsheet and a Google Document.

- `Google Document`

  - make a note of the document ID
- `Google Form`

  - select your spreadsheet as the response destination
- `Google Spreadsheet`

  - Open the sheet's Script Editor, rename the project as appropriate, and copy the script shown below. You can rename the script if you wish.
  - `var sheetName = "<<insert sheet name>>";`: edit the script to include the actual name of the sheet containing the form responses - (put the sheet name between the quotes)
  - `var docid = "<<insert document ID>>";`: edit the script to include the actual document ID - (put the ID between the quotes)
  - save the modified script
  - `Trigger`: from the menu, select "Edit, Current Projects Triggers". In the new tab that opens

    - Under "Choose which function to run", select the name of the function.
    - Under "Select event type", select "On form submit"
    - Save the trigger

**Processing**

- When a form submission is made, the spreadsheet will be updated.
- the trigger will execute the function.
- the function looks for a named range called "embeddedSheet-range" (you can change this if you wish).
- when the function executes for the first time, the range isn't found, so the function creates the range and inserts the table.
- when the functions executes thereafter, it finds the named range and replaces the it with the updated data.
- the function will replace any existing data with new data

---

```
function wa14658402() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = "<<insert sheet name>>";   // name of sheet to use
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  //get the last r and column of data
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  // define the range containing the data
  // this can be changed depending on which columns to embed
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetLR, sheetLC);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation()); 
  
  // note - this is a change mentioned in 
  // Embed Google Spreadsheet table Withing Google Document when data contains dates
  // when the data includes a data, "getValues()" fails hence
  // changing the method to "getDisplayValues()"
  var values = range.getDisplayValues(); 
  
  // get the document details
  var docid = "<<insert document ID>>";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var ranges = doc.getNamedRanges('embeddedSheet-range');
  
  if (ranges.length == 0) {
    //  Logger.log("DEBUG: ranges is zero")
    var table = body.appendTable(values);
  }
  else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: ranges is NOT zero")
    tableRange = ranges[0];
    table = tableRange.getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getElement();
    var ind = body.getChildIndex(table);
    tableRange.remove();
    body.removeChild(table);
    table = body.insertTable(ind, values);
  }
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
  rangeBuilder.addElement(table);
  doc.addNamedRange('embeddedSheet-range', rangeBuilder.build());
}
```